# Odoo <h1> field edit mode display behavior on form view

Tags: xml, odoo

I have a name field between `<h1>` tags on a form view.

When the text needs 2 lines to be displayed, everything works well. 
But only in read! When the record is in edit mode, the text is displayed on one line only, hiding the beginning.

How can I set this field to display as many lines as it needs on edit mode? (same display behavior than read mode).

*What I have been able to achieve so far: display the field on full width by placing it in a `<group>` tag rather than `<div>`.*

EDIT: 
Just need to use fields.text rather than fields.char..

Comment: can you post your code please

Comment: I need to use fields.text instead of fields.char

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use fields.text rather than fields.char